# Payment Stripe With Asset Unistripe Unity Worked In Development Build But Not In Production Build C# Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, stripe-payments

I have make an app with unity. The app have a payment feature which i used a **stripe** as my payment gateway. I also use asset from unity call **Unistripe** to just create a **token**.

The apps and the payment work well when in development build (where I tick development build and script debugging in player setting and then build and run) But when i untick development build and script debugging for production release the payment is not working.

What could possible cause the payment not working ? Is there something that i am missing in here ? Or is there any setting that i am missing in here ?

Or

Is there any code that i am missing in here ?

Thank You

Note : This apps is a donation. So it is permitted to use a third party payment.

Edited :

This is the error from the log cat :

```
"java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:80" 
 "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.onevcat.UniStripe.UniStripe"
```

Comment: Is there a specific error you're seeing? If you look in http://dashboard.stripe.com/logs do you see any errors when trying to collect cards? More detail would help other folks troubleshoot!

Comment: Thanks @duck but i have solve the problem now. I found the solution. I have update the answer and edit the question for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem myself. So the problem is there is a class didn't include in the final bundle when build.

So when build the game, i have set the build system to **"Grade"** and set the minify **to "Proguard"**.

This setting didn't keep all the class when build. If you want to keep all the class you must set the config in the Proguard_text.txt to keep the file when build.

So to easy solve this problem i just change the build system to **"Internal (Deprecated)"** since this build system keep all the class.

That's all.

**Note :** use proguard and change the proguard_text.txt config to keep the "com.onevcat.UniStripe.UniStripe" didn't worked as well. Maybe they are more class didn't include in the final bundle.

**For more :**

*To keep the class Just type :*

-keep class com.onevcat.UniStripe.**